# Hide row numbers and column letters in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Simple one I know, but I can't seem to find a way to hide the row numbers and column letters on a Google Sheet.

I know that you can do it on MS Excel but is it possible to do it on Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible

You may want to take a look at File > Publish to the web. Spreadsheets published this way are read-only and do not show row numbers or column labels.

See https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37579 and https://support.google.com/drive/answer/55244 for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking to embed it on a Google Site for users to view and change it, so read-only is not an option. One of the many little annoyances with Google Docs!

Comment: And unfortunately "Published" sheets do not update live like the standard ones do.

Comment: Nov 2018. Still not possible :(